# Seeing Huge Amount of Data Usage with Google Music

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, data-monitoring, google-play-music

I have recently purchased the Galaxy Nexus, and I am extremely happy with it. As part of that purchase, I decided to bring all my music into Google Music. So, I've been using Google Music on my way into and home from work (about an hour total a day) and I am seeing a huge amount of data usage from Google Music. (Everything else combined doesn't come close to what it uses.)

Here is a screenshot of my data management window:

[image: Google Music Data Usage]

Why is this happening? Is there anything I can do to prevent it from heavily using data like it is?

Comment: An hour total should use ~144 MB for 320 kb/s music.  Less that double that for 6 days seems perfectly reasonable given that your music is probably not all that quality.  Why do you think it should be less?

Comment: @MatthewRead - I guess, based on what I have seen in the past with Pandora, this seems significantly higher. I could listen with about the same frequency on Pandora and it didn't use nearly the same amount of data. Guess I should be glad that I am still grandfathered on the unlimited plan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I think the answer to your question is that [Pandora's stream is never more than 64 kbps](http://help.pandora.com/customer/portal/articles/90985-audio-quality) for mobile devices, whereas [Google Music uses 320 kbps MP3s](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/networking/google-music-your-great-music-locker-in-the-cloud-review/1671) and [there's no downsampling](http://pansentient.com/2011/09/google-music-beta-vs-spotify/).  That's 5 times the amount of data, assuming Pandora doesn't use a better format than MP3.

Since Google Music transcodes your files, I don't think you have much of an option here.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I was afraid it was something like that. I guess I'll have it download my content on my wireless connection so I can go on long trips without racking up huge amounts of data charges.